# ASPNETCOMPILER "Object reference not set to an instance of an object when trying to publish from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I used the NuGet package manager to open a nupkg file. After that, I can build, but my publish fails. The error is in the website:

225 Object reference not set to an instance of an object and file is listed as ASPNETCOMPILER with no line/column noted.

I uninstalled NuGet package manager as some had suggested, and still get the error. Any ideas?

Thanks for any help at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the NuGet install had inserted a block of code in my web.config files, which was subsequently updated and deleted. Adding that block of code back in solved the problem.